# How to set guild_subscriptions event to true in discord.py?

Tags: bots, discord.py, ctx

I am facing a problem in discord.py, the following code is running perfectly, but `ctx.guild.owner` returns none, and in documentation it says that if this happens the event `guild_subscriptions` is set to `False`, how can I set this event to `True` in order to make it work? I can't find any solution in discord.py documentation, neither Google.

The code of my `serverstats` command:

```
@commands.command(name="serverstats", aliases = ["serverinfo", "si", "ss", "check-stats", 'cs'])
    async def serverstats(self, ctx: commands.Context):

        embed = discord.Embed(
            color = discord.Colour.orange(),
            title = f"{ctx.guild.name}")


        embed.set_thumbnail(url = f"{ctx.guild.icon_url}")
        embed.add_field(name = "ID", value = f"{ctx.guild.id}")
        embed.add_field(name = "Owner", value = f"{ctx.guild.owner}")
        embed.add_field(name = "Region", value = f"{ctx.guild.region}")
        embed.add_field(name = "Member Count", value = f"{ctx.guild.member_count}")
        embed.add_field(name = "Created at", value = f"{ctx.guild.created_at}")
        embed.set_footer(icon_url = f"{ctx.author.avatar_url}", text = f"Requested by {ctx.author.name}")

        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the event guild_subscriptions is set to False
>
> I can't find any solution in discord.py documentation

It's not an *event*. The docs say it's a parameter when creating a `commands.Bot instance`, and that you [*can*](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client) find in the documentation for Clients, which you can. If you scroll down to the bottom of that list of parameters, you'll see `guild_subscriptions(bool)`, which is what you're looking for.

To enable this, all you have to do is add it to the code where you create your Client:

```
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=your_prefix, guild_subscriptions=True)
```

Also, since Discord 1.5 you now need to pass the correct `Intents`, and the documentation for Client states that you need to have `Intents.members` enabled if you don't want `guild.owner` to return `None`, which is also what's causing your issue. You also have to pass these intents as a parameter, so the final thing would end up looking something like this:

```
# Configure intents (1.5.0)
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=your_prefix, guild_subscriptions=True, intents=intents)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for help! I really apreciate it! It works now!