# Why is discord.py's client.event not working and how do I fix it?

Tags: python, discord.py, bots

I am trying to get my bot to list when a user's status changes. What it should do is send a message in a certain channel whenever someone's discord status changes. However, I constantly get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 9, in <module>
    cmdEXE.all(token)
  File "/home/runner/Geek-Bot/Commands/cmdEXE.py", line 9, in all
    async def on_member_update(before, after):
TypeError: event() missing 1 required positional argument: 'coro'
```

I have no idea what I should put in the "coro" argument, and I can't find a way to fix it. Here is my code:

```
@client.event
async def on_member_update(before, after):
    await client.get_channel(786336506247512094).send('To be edited')
```

Comment: Are you sure this code in its given form raises this error? This error should only occur if you did ``@client.event()`` instead of ``@client.event``

Comment: I am positive. I have double-checked my code and I have found no parts with @client.event() @Lucas

Comment: How about your ``client`` variable, can you show how you define that

Comment: @Lucas
import discord
client = discord.Client

Comment: @Simon you mean `discord.Client()`?

Comment: @FlexGames ‍♂️ Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

you can find in the [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html) for Clients, which you can. If you scroll down to the bottom of that list of parameters, you'll see `guild_subscriptions(bool)`, which is what you're looking for.

to enable u can try this:

```
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = 'your-perfix', guild_subscriptions=True)
```

Discord 1.5 you now need to pass the correct `Intents`, and the documentation for Client states that you need to have `Intents.members` enabled if you don't want `guild.owner` to return `None`, which is also what's causing your issue. You also have to pass these intents as a parameter, so the final thing would end up looking something like this:

```
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = 'your-perfix', guild_subscriptions=True, intents=intents)
```

Hope can fix your code, [Thanks to this people](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64517612/how-to-set-guild-subscriptions-event-to-true-in-discord-py)